# using list of options in textFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter app, in the app there is a form for registration which contain some textFormfields,

as bellow :

[image]

in the gender field, there should be a list of options {Male, Female, Other} the user can select himself, and I don't know how to create it.
any idea???

Comment: Go with dropdown in flutter or customise as per requirement.

Comment: how can i connect dropdown with textFormField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flutter DropDownButton for this purpose. here is the code from documentation which you can try yourself:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

for more information you can visit [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Comment: and how to connect it with the form?

Comment: forms have children, this will be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`dropdownfield`](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdownfield) package available on pud.dev. Here is an eg for your use case.
You can use it with/without other textformfields inside a Form widget for using validators.

```
DropDownField(
    textStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    hintText: "Gender",
    controller: genderController,
    value: genderController.text,
    items: ["Male","Female","Others"],
    onValueChanged: (value) {
        //process logic over here on value change
    },
    setter: (value) {
        //set new value
    },
),
```

Hope this provides you the solution. But for a field like gender, I would recommend using a dropdown. Use this kind of field when there are a lot of options to choose from.